# Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line) in build.gradle.kts

Tags: android, gradle, jitpack

[image: that is a screen shot of the error message]

I can't add jitpack to build.gradle.kts
it shows an error " Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line) "

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

}

Comment: You are using Groovy syntax in a Kotlin script Gradle file. Try `maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") }`. See [the Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:maven_repo).

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks it works with me

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Support for Kotlin Gradle scripts is fairly new in Android — for example, Android Studio only added support for it in version 4.0. Most of the instructions that you will see online will be for Groovy Gradle scripts, and you will need to make some minor conversions.

In this case, this Groovy:

```
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

...turns into this Kotlin:

```kotlin
maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") }
```

Comment: great. it works for java also.

Answer (score 6):

Problem might be .. as you mentioned that the problem is in "**in build.gradle.kts**" this means you are using kotlin gradle script.
So, simply change `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` to `maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") }`.

Or,

Rather than you can also skip adding `maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") }` in **build.kts** and simply go to settings.gradle and add this dependency here : -

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") } // Here is your dependency
```

}
}

Answer (score 3):

**Gradle 8.4 dependency use TOML** **Kotlin**

1. `setting.gradle.kts`, Here must register **jitpack** :

   dependencyResolutionManagement {
   repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
   repositories {

   ```
       google()

       mavenCentral()

       maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") }
    }
   ```

   }
2. libs.versions.toml: below Gradle Script, there is a file is called TOML.In this version of Gradle, all the decencies must determine in this file by URL, version.(example: GitHub)

[image]

[versions]

```
advanced_menu = "1.0.0"

agp = "8.3.0-alpha17"


[libraries]

advanced_menu_mori = { module = "com.github.Mori-hub:Advanced_Menu", version.ref = "advanced_menu" }

androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtx" }
```

3.build.gradle.kts(:app): Finally, add new lib in the dependencies by new pattern ->

**libs.name is defined in toml file** separated by dot

dependencies {

```
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation (libs.advanced.menu.mori)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though all the above answers are correct in their own way, just wanted to highlight that

Gradle Script files written using the Kotlin DSL do not accept a single quote (') for defining strings. You should use double quotes (") wherever applicable. And also, you should use braces with the `because`, `implementation` and `api` keywords

For example

```
implementation 'com.simpl.android:fingerprintSDK:1.1.2'  {
        because 'We use Simpl SDK for Payment'
    }
```

is invalid

But

```
implementation("com.simpl.android:fingerprintSDK:1.1.2")  { // Replaced with brackets and double quotes
        because("We use Simpl SDK for Payment")
    }
```

is valid