# Cannot resolve jitpack dependencies in android studio in the last gradle version

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, jitpack

I get `Failed to resolve: com.github.dogecoin:libdohj:v0.15.9` error and I don't know why. I also tried other jitpack dependencies. It works fine in my previous projects.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.2'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I added the `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` to the settings.gradle and it fixed the issue.

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

    }
}
rootProject.name = "Crypto World"
include ':app'
```

Comment: Also, if your dependencies contain capital letters make them small, for example, implementation 'com.github.SomeName:SomeProject:2.0.1 make it implementation 'com.github.somename.someproject:2.0.1

Comment: Why isnt this in the official documentation?? I got the same problem and this fixed it for me. THANKS!

Comment: Seriously!  This should definitely be in the documentation!  Thanks @Mehranjp73

Comment: This works for me. Besides adding maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }. I also had to change repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS) to repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS).

Answer (score 3):

In the new version **(7.2)** of Gradle some parts is changed, so you need to do like this:

1-Check your `gradle` version

2- Open the `build.gradle(project:---)`

3- If like the below code, go to next

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

4- Open `stting.gradle(---)`

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
```

5- Sync Now and finish

Comment: I do not have the following code as in your step 3, Do I have to add it there for each jitpack library I am importing or it was there for you already for some other library?                   `plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
}`

Comment: @MayankSinghal, yes, you can

Answer (score 0):

**Gradle 8.4 dependency use TOML Kotlin**

`setting.gradle.kts`, Here, must register **jitpack** :

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {

 repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS) 

repositories {

    google()

    mavenCentral()

    maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") }
 }
}
```

for more information please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77630378/12272687) https://stackoverflow.com/a/77630378/12272687